# How to set up JMeter plugin through powershell

Tags: setup, jmeter

I am trying to set up JMeter in a VM through powershell(no RDP provision). I am able to down the plugins but extracting the files into lib\ext doesn't bring up the add on in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve by following the steps mentioned in 
https://jmetervn.com/2016/12/14/how-to-install-plugins-in-jmeter-3-x-via-command-line/